# $n_1,...,n_k$ pair coprime $\!\iff\! {\rm lcm}(n_1,...,n_k)=n_1...n_k$ [lcm = product for coprimes]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

$n_1,...,n_k$ pairwise coprime $\iff LCM(n_1,...,n_k)=n_1...n_k$

Recently, I was told this as part of a larger proof concerning direct products of groups. I am wondering why this is true.

Comment: See [GCD to LCM of multiple numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319297/gcd-to-lcm-of-multiple-numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you prove the following two statements?

1. If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ then $ab \mid c$.
2. If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,c) = 1$ then $gcd(a,bc) = 1$.

Then, use induction to show that $n_1 \dots n_k$ divides $\text{lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_k)$. Since $n_1\dots n_k$ is a common multiple that divides the least common multiple, it must be equal to the least common multiple.

Comment: That hint  work for $(\Rightarrow)$, but You forgot to handle the converse direction $\(\Leftarrow)\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

We notate $\,n_1,n_2,\ldots, n_k\,$ as $\,a,b,\cdots, i,j,\,$ with $\rm lcm = \ell$.

$(\Leftarrow)\,\ \ n\mid i,j\,\Rightarrow\,  a,\ldots i,j\, \mid\, a\cdots ij/n,\,$ so $\,\ell = a\cdots i\:\!j\mid a\cdots i\:\!j/n\Rightarrow n\mid 1,\,$ so $\,(i,j)\!=\!1$

$(\Rightarrow)\,\ $ Write $\,[a,b,\ldots]:= {\rm lcm}(a,b,\ldots).\,$ We induct using  $\,\color{#c00}{\rm U} = $ [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242)

$$ a_1,\ldots,a_k\mid m\!\!\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm U\!\!}}\iff [a_1,\ldots,a_k]\mid m\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\  $$

Induct: $  $ base case: $\ k=2\!:\,\  (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow [a,b] = ab_{\phantom{|}}\,$ by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194978/242)
The induction step $\,k>2\,$ is as follows, using the base case and  $\color{#c00}{\rm U}$ a few times

$$\begin{align}[a,b,...,j]\mid m &\iff a,\,b,\ldots,j\ \mid m\\[.2em]
&\iff  a,[b,\ldots,j]\mid m\\[.2em]
&\iff a,\ b\ \cdots\:\  j\  \mid\, m,\ \ \ \text{by induction}\\[.2em]
&\iff a\cdot b\ \cdots\:\  j\  \mid\, m,\ \ \ \text{by base case $\,k = 2\,$ and by}
\end{align} $$

employing: $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,b,\ldots,j\iff a\,$ coprime to $\,b\cdots j,\,$ by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242)

**Remark** $ $ Above "$\!\!\iff\!\!$" chain implies $[a,...,j]$ and $\,a\cdots j\,$ divide each other (i.e. are *associate*), so being $> 0$ in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ they're equal. In general domains the best we can say is that they are equal up to a unit multiple. But in many cases we can effectively [unit normalize GCDs and LCMs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242) to get equality there too (or we can ignore unit factors by working in the monoid quotient modulo the unit group).

Comment: Please do not answer questions that don't meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It seems you missed this was*$7$ years ago (when different methods were used by I (and others)). Of course views on meta matters do frequently change over time - as the site evolves.