# Why does the CRT formula yield a solution of a congruence system?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I understand there is a method for solving simultaneous modular equations. For example;
$$x = 2 \mod{3}$$
$$x = 3 \mod{5}$$
$$x = 2 \mod{7}$$
We find numbers equal to the product of every given modulo except one of them - giving $5 \cdot 7$, $3 \cdot 7$ and $3 \cdot 5$. We then find the multiplicative inverses of these numbers with modulo equal to the number missing from the product. The numbers found are then 2, 1 and 1 in this case. The value of x is then given by:
$$x = 2 \cdot (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot (3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1 = 233 = 23 \mod{3\cdot5\cdot7}$$

But I do not understand how this method correctly gives the value of $x$. I understand that the Chinese remainder theorem proves that there is a unique value of $0\le x \lt 3\cdot5\cdot7 \mod{3\cdot5\cdot7}$ but can someone please explain why this method finds this value of x?

Comment: It's not clear which part proves troublesome. Often it is the linearity that I describe in my answer. If it is something else then please elaborate and I can add further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generalisation of the formula for the solutions of a system of *two* congruences modulo two coprime numbers $a$ and $b$?. This formula uses a Bézout's relation: $\;ua+vb=1$ and it is:
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv \alpha\mod a,\\
x\equiv \beta\mod b,
\end{cases}
\quad\text{which is }\qquad x\equiv \beta ua+\alpha vb\mod ab$$

Indeed we have $\;\beta ua+\alpha vb\equiv \alpha vb\equiv \alpha\mod a$ since  $\;vb\equiv 1\mod a$. Similarly modulo $b$.

Now, as $v \equiv b^{-1}\bmod a\:$ and $\;u\equiv a^{-1}\bmod b$, this formula can be written as
$$x\equiv \beta\, a (a^{-1}\bmod b)+\alpha\, b(b^{-1}\bmod a)\mod ab.$$

*Some details with the example in the question*:

In each term of $x$:
$$ 2 \cdot (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot (3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1 $$
the first factor is the r.h.s. of a congruence equation mod. $m_i$, the second (between parentheses) is the product of the other moduli and the last factor is the inverse of the former mod. $m_i$.

For instance, consider the first congruence: as $5\cdot 7\equiv 2\mod 3$, which is its own inverse, and $\equiv 0\mod 5,7$,we see that
$$(5\cdot7)\cdot 2\begin{cases}\equiv 1\mod3,\\[1ex]\equiv 0 \mod 5,7 \end{cases}\quad\text{hence }\quad\alpha\cdot(5\cdot7)\cdot 2\begin{cases}\equiv \alpha\mod3\\[1ex]\equiv 0 \mod 5,7 \end{cases}$$
So we obtain a formula analog to *Lagrange's interpolation formula*:
$$ \alpha \cdot (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 + \beta \cdot (3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1 + \gamma\cdot (3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1 \equiv\begin{cases}\alpha\mod 3, \\[1ex]\beta\mod 5,\\[1ex]\gamma\mod 7. \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Existence** of a solution $\,x\,$ of the congruence system becomes clearer if we  highlight the innate *linearity* at the heart of the Chinese Remainder Theorem [CRT] [formula,](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chinese_Remainder_Theorem) i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
x\, =\ &a&\!\color{#0a0}{\overbrace{(-5\cdot 7)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}3)}} \,+\,  &b& \overbrace{(\color{#c00}3\cdot 7)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 5)}\, +\, &c&\overbrace{(\color{#c00}3\cdot 5)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 7)}\quad {\bf[CRT]}\\ \\
\Longrightarrow\ \ x\,\equiv\ &a&\ ({\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}3),\ \ x\equiv &b&\ ({\rm mod}\ 5),\ \ x\equiv &c&\ ({\rm mod}\ 7)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

since, e.g. when reduced $\!\bmod  \color{#c00}3,\,$ the 2nd and 3rd summands are $\equiv\color{#c00} 0,\,$ both having factors of $\,\color{#c00}3,\,$ so the formula reduces to  $\, x\equiv a\color{#0a0}{(1)} \color{#c00}{+ 0 + 0}\equiv a,\,$ as sought. Similarly reducing the CRT formula $\!\bmod 5\,$ and $\!\bmod 7\,$ shows  $\,x\equiv b\pmod{\!5}\,$ and $\,x\equiv c\pmod{\!7},\,$  resp. hence the CRT formula for $\,x\,$ does indeed yield a simultaneous solution of all $3$ congruences in our system, as sought.

**Key Idea** the overbraced terms are $\color{#0a0}{\equiv 1}\:\!$ mod one modulus, and $\color{#c00}{\equiv 0}\:\!$ mod all others. More clearly, if we write the system in *vector* form $\ x\equiv (a,b,c)\,$ mod $\,(3,5,7)\,$ then $\rm\,[CRT]$ becomes

$\qquad x\, :=\, a\,\color{#0a0}{(1,0,0)} + b\,(0,1,0) + c\,(0,0,1)\equiv (a.b,c)\ $ as desired. $\qquad [\bf Linearity]$

by the green term $\,\color{#0a0}{g \equiv 1}\ ({\rm mod}\ 3),\ \color{#0a0}{g\equiv 0}\ ({\rm mod}\ 5),\  \color{#0a0}{g\equiv 0}\ ({\rm mod}\ 7),\ $ i.e. $\ \color{#0a0}{g^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\equiv (1,0,0)}\ {\rm mod}\ (3,5,7),\, $ and similarly for $\,(0,1,0)\,$ and $\,(0,0,1).$

Thus once we compute the solutions for the "basis" vectors $(1,0,0),\ (0,1,0),\ (0,0,1)$ we can exploit [Linearity] to generate the general solution as a linear combination of these basic solutions.

Solving for the basis is easy: $\,{\color{#0a0}{5,7\mid g}\,\Rightarrow\, 35\mid g},\, $ so $\bmod 3\!:\ \color{#0a0}{1\equiv g} \equiv 35n\equiv -n\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv -1,\,$ i.e. $\,n =\,$ inverse of the product $35 = 5\cdot 7$ of all other moduli. Hence the common CRT formula.

The innate algebraic structure will be clarified if you later study abstract algebra, where you will learn  the [ring theoretic view of CRT,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805851/242) and vector spaces and modules (elaborated briefly below).

---

**Uniqueness** $ $ The solutions of the system $\,x\equiv a_i\pmod{\!m_i},\, i = 1,\ldots, k\,$ [are *unique*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) modulo the moduli product $M = m_1 m_2\cdots m_k,\,$ i.e if $\,x,\,x'\,$ are solutions then $\,x\equiv x'\pmod{\!M}.\,$ Indeed, being solutions $\Rightarrow x'\equiv a_i\equiv x\pmod{\!m_i}\,$ so $\,x'-x\,$ is divisible by all  $\,m_i\,$ so it is divisible by their lcm, [which is  their product $M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841440/242), since the $\,m_i$ pairwise coprime (by hypothesis). Hence the *least* natural solution is $\,x\bmod M$. [This proof is a special case of the fact that general solution of a linear system of equations is given by adding any particular solution to the general solution of the associated homogeneous system, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488370/242) and its links. In our case the associated homogeneous system is $$\,x\equiv 0\!\!\pmod{m_i}\iff m_i \mid x\iff {\rm lcm}(m_i)\!=\!M\mid x\iff x = nM\qquad\quad$$ so the general solution is $\,x = x_0 + nM\,$ for any particular root $\,x_0,\,$ e.g. from CRT formula].

---

**Product Ring View** $ $ The arithmetical essence of the matter will be clarified *structurally* if you study abstract algebra, where CRT becomes a ring isomorphism $\,\Bbb Z/M\, \cong\,  \Bbb Z/m_1 \times \cdots \Bbb Z/m_k.\,$ This means that an integer $\!\bmod M\,$ can be represented as vector $(k$-tuple) whose components are its values in each factor
$$n\bmod \overbrace{m_1\cdots m_k}^{M}\,\mapsto\, (n\bmod m_1, \ldots, n\bmod m_k)$$

CRT says this map is a bijection, and gives a formula showing how to recover the value of $\,n\bmod M\,$ from the values $\,n\bmod m_i\,$ in its vector rep. Further this vector representation is compatible with addition and multiplication by performing each operation *componentwise*, e.g.
$$\begin{align} -5\cdot 7\ \ +\ \ 3\cdot 7\ \ +\ \ 3\cdot 5\ \ \ &\equiv\,\ 1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \pmod{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}\\[.3em]
\iff \ (1,0,0)\!+\!(0,1,0)\!+\!(0,0,1) &\equiv\,  (1,1,1)\! \pmod{3,\,5,\,7}\end{align}\qquad$$

Hence these vectors with componentwise addition and multiplication yield essentially the same "number system" as the integers $\!\bmod M.\,$ This arithmetical similarity of number systems is made more precise in abstract algebra via the notion of *isomorphic rings*.

---

**Lagrange Interpolation** formula is a special case of above CRT formula, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556444/242).

Comment: what is the reason why x lies in mod m at the last?

Comment: @mathmaniage It is not clear what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: I don't really get the reason why does x lie in mod m world? if m=$m_1m_2...m_k$ where $m_i$ are coprime, why does our solution fall into the mod m world? Could you mathematically deduce this?

Comment: @mathmaniage The OP's question asked only about the *existence* half of CRT, i.e. why the CRT solution formula is correct. Your question is about the *uniqueness* half of CRT, i.,e, why it is the only solution modulo the product of the moduli. I edited the answer to explain this too.

Comment: thank you this was the confusion in my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209237/crt-adding-numbers-in-two-different-mod-worlds/3209331?noredirect=1#comment6606885_3209331

Comment: but is there a more mathematical treatment to this to show that the answer is modulo m because their lcm divides them? If there is, could you please show it in the aforementioned link

Comment: @mathmaniage I hadn't see your question. added more to my edit to explain the ring view.

Comment: @mathmaniage CRT tells us how to construct a particular solutions $x_0$ of the system of congruences. Further it implies that an integer $x$ is a solution $\iff  x\equiv x_0 \pmod{\!M},\,$ so solutions are *unique* $\bmod M.\,$ This completely characterizes the integer solutions of the congruence system.  Are  you  asking why lcm = product for pairwise coprime integers?

Comment: thank you, I finally understand.

Comment: @mathmaniage Great!

Answer (score 0):

Taking Bill Dubuque's graphic answer and graphically expanding on it:

$x = 2 \cdot\overbrace{ (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2}^{\equiv 1 \pmod 3\\ \equiv 0 \pmod 5\\ \equiv 0 \pmod 7} + 3 \cdot \overbrace{(3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1}^{\equiv 0 \pmod 3\\ \equiv 1 \pmod 5\\ \equiv 0 \pmod 7} + 2 \cdot \overbrace{(3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1}^{\equiv 0 \pmod 3\\ \equiv 0 \pmod 5\\ \equiv 1\pmod 7}\equiv\, \overbrace{2,\,3,\,2\pmod{3,5,7}}^{\equiv 2 + 0 +0\pmod 3\\ \equiv0+3+0 \pmod 5\\ \equiv 0+0+2\pmod 7}$

======

Think about what you, *yourself* just stated.

If take  this sum $x = 2 \cdot (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot (3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1$ and $\mod 3$ it, then $(5\cdot 7)$ and $2$ are inverses so $2\cdot[(5\cdot 7)\cdot 2]\pmod 3\equiv 2\cdot 1\pmod 3 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.  ANd the other terms are multiples of $3$ so they are $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  So  $x\equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

If you take that term $x = 2 \cdot (5 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (3 \cdot 7) \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot (3 \cdot 5) \cdot 1$ and $\mod 5$ it, then $3\cdot 7$ and $1$ are inverses so $3\cdot[(3\cdot 7) \cdot 1] \equiv 3 \cdot 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.  ANd the other terms are multiples of $5$.  So the sum $x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.

And so on.

....

If you want to solve

$x \equiv a \pmod m$

$x \equiv b \pmod n$

$x \equiv c \pmod v$ then

And assuming you were able find $(nv)^{-1}\mod m; (mv)^{-1}\mod n; $and $(nm)^{-1}\mod v$

Then Let $K = a(nv)^{-1}(nv) + b (mv)^{-1}(mv) + c(nm)^{-1}(nm)$

Note:  $K \pmod m \equiv$

$a(nv)^{-1}(nv) + b (mv)^{-1}(mv) + c(nm)^{-1}(nm)\pmod m\equiv$

$a*1 + [b(mv)^{-1}v]m + [c(nm)^{-1}n]m \pmod m\equiv$

$a*1 + 0 + 0 \equiv a\pmod m$.

And likewise:

$K \pmod n \equiv$

$a(nv)^{-1}(nv) + b (mv)^{-1}(mv) + c(nm)^{-1}(nm)\pmod n\equiv$

$[a(nv)^{-1}v]n + b*1 + [c(nm)^{-1}m]n \pmod n\equiv$

$0 + b*1 + 0 \equiv b\pmod n$.

And

$a(nv)^{-1}(nv) + b (mv)^{-1}(mv) + c(nm)^{-1}(nm)\pmod v\equiv$

$[a(nv)^-1n]v + [b(mv)^{-1}m]v + c*1 \pmod v\equiv$

$0 + 0 + c \equiv c\pmod m$.

So $K$ is *A* solution.

If $m,n,v$ are pairwise relative prime then $K$ is a unique solution upto $\mod nmv$.

Comment: @fleabood, but that misses the point that K obtained in step 1 , K obtained in step 2 and in step 3 the sum of which is the solution upto modnmv