# CRT- adding numbers in two different mod worlds

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The proof of the CRT goes as follows:
Given the number $x \epsilon Z_m$, $m=m_1m_2...m_k$
$$M_k = m/m_k$$
construct:
$$ x = a_1M_1y_1+a_2M_2y_2+...+a_nM_ny_n$$
where $y_k$ is the particular inverse of $M_k\ mod\ m_k$
$$\Rightarrow x\equiv a_kM_ky_k\equiv a_k(mod\ m_k)$$

What I don't understand is:
how is $x\equiv a_1M_1y_1+a_2M_2y_2+...+a_kM_ky_k$ and this lies in $mod\ m$? Is this because there is some rule in modular arithmetic for adding two numbers in two different mod worlds like: $c \mod d \ + e\ mod f = (c+d)(mod(ef))$? As far as I know, there isn't one like that. And how does the addition of these items all in a different mod world provide the solution for x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part 2 of the chinese remainder theorem, [which starts off at this page and continues to the next](https://forthright48.com/chinese-remainder-theorem-part-1-coprime-moduli/), explains the concept of lcm required to understand the OP's question and the concept why the solution exists in mod m, which is actually only a way of finding the minimum solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think $x$ is calculated in $\mathbf Z$, using  representatives of $M_k^{-1}\bmod m_k$. Note that the congruence class of $x$ $\bmod m$ is independent of the choice of the representatives.

Comment: but why do we mod m? What is the cause for it?

Comment: and why do the moduli have to be pairwise relatively prime?

Comment: I don't quite see your problem. The Chinese Remainder theorem is about solving systems of congruences. Isn't that clear to you?

Comment: yes, that's clear but why does $x$ lie in mod m? what's the reason for it?

Comment: That's what the C.R.T. is about: you have a set of congruence equation modulo $m_1, m_2,\dots, m_k$ and you can deduce a common solution. The C.R.T. asserts that if the $m_i$ are pairwise coprime, this solution is unique modulo $m_1m_2\dotsm m_k$.

Comment: yes, but, I've seen a couple of books and resources, but nowhere does it mathematically deduce that the solution lies in mod m, where $m=m_1m_2...m_k$

Comment: The formulation I know asserts there is a ring isomorphism $$\mathbf Z/m_1\dotsm m_k\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/m_1\mathbf Z\times\dotsm\times\mathbf Z/m_k\mathbf Z $$.

Comment: Is this something we can understand without abstract algebra? Can you point to a link or something for understanding this deduction?

Comment: Maybe this [web page](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/crt.html) ?

Comment: yep that was it, it explains the reason, but, I didnt understand this part: if $z\equiv a mod p$ and y is the solution z-y is a multiple of pq, if p and q are coprime, why do they need to be coprime? and why should $z-y \geq pq.$

Comment: That's because if both $y,z\equiv a\mod p$ and $y,z\equiv b \mod q$; it means that $y-a$ and $z-a$ are divisible by $p$, whenve $z-y$ is also divisible by $p$. Similarly, you can check $z-y$ is divisible by $q$. So as it's divisible by both $p$ and $q$, Gauß'lemma says that, if $p$ and $q$ are coprime, it's divisible by $pq$. If they're not coprime , you can't be sure of the conclusion. For instance, $20$ is divisible by $4$ and by $10$; but it's not divisible by $40$.

Comment: Gauß'lemma? Google only found gauss lemma, but, that was related to polynomial. Is that the one you meant?

Comment: and can't the product of pq exceed (z-y) in which case it wouldn't be divisible?

Comment: It's a consequence of an arithmetic Gauß' lemma I meant. The lemma itself says that if $a$ divides $bc$ and is coprime to $b$, it divides $c$. If I remember well, all this can be proved from Bézout's identity.

Comment: If $pq>z-y$, it implies $z-y=0$, i.e. z=y$.

Comment: but the lemma you mention, its for $a|bc$ where a and b are coprime, but here, it's more like: $pq|x$ where p and q are coprime, where x=(z-y)

Comment: I donn't remember the exact proof at the ùmoment, but all these results ultimately rely on Bézout.