# Isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ to $ \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, group-isomorphism

Hello I have a difficulty with this exercise the idea is to show
$$\begin{align}
\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{30} &\to  \mathbb{Z}_2\times  \mathbb{Z}_3\times  \mathbb{Z}_5 \\
 [x]_{30} &\mapsto ([x]_2,[x]_3,[x]_5)
\end{align}$$
is surjective but what I was able to show is that
$$\begin{align}
\phi_1: \mathbb{Z}_{30} &\to  \mathbb{Z}_2\times  \mathbb{Z}_{15} \\
[x]_{30} & \mapsto  ([x]_2,[x]_{15})
\end{align}
$$
is surjective
I wanted to consider  $$\begin{align}
\phi_2 : \mathbb{Z}_2\times  \mathbb{Z}_{15} & \to  \mathbb{Z}_2\times  \mathbb{Z}_3\times  \mathbb{Z}_5 \\
([x]_2,[x]_{15}) & \mapsto ([x]_2,[x]_3,[x]_5)
\end{align}$$  and show that is surjective but but I can't show $\phi_2$ is surjective
I need help to tackle this exercise

Comment: Hint: $\ \ 3\cdot 5\to (1,0,0),\ 2\cdot 5\to (0,1,0),\ 2\cdot 3\to (0,0,1),\,$ thus $\,15a + 10b+6c\to (a,b,c),\,$ by *linearity*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) for the idea (CRT formula).

Comment: The domain and codomain both have cardinality thirty. Therefore bijectivity (and also surjectivity) is automatic once you show injectivity, i.e. that the kernel is trivial. To get an explicit inverse you need to work a bit harder. Bezout's identity and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(b_1,b_2)\in  \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15} $  and  consider $ a=-14b_2+15b_1$
with  have $ \phi(a)=(b_1,b_2)$
since $ [a]_2=b_1, [a]_{15}=b_2$