# For pairwise coprime $a_1<\cdots<a_n$ and $b_i=((a_1\cdots a_n)/a_i)^{-1} \text{ mod } a_i$, $0>b_i>-a_i$, when $b=-1/a + \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i/a_i)=-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $2\leq a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$ be pairwise coprime integers, let $a=a_1 \cdots a_n$, and let $b_i$ be the unique integer such that $b_i=(a/a_i)^{-1} \text{ mod } a_i$ and $0>b_i>-a_i$. Then let $b=-1/a + \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i/a_i) $. It is known that $b$ is a negative integer such that $-n<b\leq -1$.

Actually I am studying Saveliev's book *Invariants for homology 3-spheres*, and the integer $b$ arises here in the following way: The Seifert-fibered homology sphere $\Sigma(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ (defined in chapter 1.1.4) bounds a unique negative definite plumbing 4-manifold whose graph is a star-shaped tree, and the weight of the central node is exactly $b$.

Consider the case $n=4$, so in this case $b=-1, -2$ or $-3$. Is there a way to find a condition for $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ so that $b=-1$? (Or at least an example.) I computed $b$ for some small $a_i$'s; for example if $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(2,3,5,7)$ then $b=-2$, and if $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(2,5,7,11)$ then $b=-2$, and I couldn't find  $(a_1,\dots,a_4)$ with $b=-1$. I am wondering to find a criterion for $(a_1,\dots,a_4)$ to have $b=-1$ by using some number theory, etc.

Comment: Let $\,x\,$ be the solution of $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{\!a_i},\, i=1,\cdots, n\,$ that is given by the well-known [CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242), so $\,x = 1+a\:\!b,\,$ for some $\,b\in \Bbb Z.\,$ Your $\,b\,$ is the "CRT quotient" $\, b = (x\!-\!1)/a\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes but $x$ is determined only modulo $\prod_i a_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b=-1$:

$n\ \ (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$

$3\ \ (2, 3, 7)\ (2, 5, 7)\ (3, 4, 5)\ (4, 5, 7)\ (5, 6, 7)\ ...$

$4\ \ (2, 5, 9, 13)\ (3, 4, 7, 11)\ (3, 5, 8, 11)\ (5, 8, 9, 11)\ ...$

$5\ \ (3, 4, 11, 13, 19)\ (5, 7, 13, 16, 19)\ (5, 11, 14, 17, 19)\ ...$

$6\ \ (5, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17)\ (4, 7, 13, 17, 19, 23)\ (7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 23)\ ...$

Comment: Thanks. Did you find these examples by hand?

Comment: I find them by computer. I haven't found any criterion yet.