# Number Theory: What does $\theta_i$ mean here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, chinese-remainder-theorem

(Posting this again since the last one was an image and people told me to write it down).

Found this from this [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44499-8_27.pdf) (Page 4; Section 4.1). [Image version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2zLt.jpg)

I wanted help in understand what $\theta_{i}$ and $x = ( x_{1},\dots,x_{k} ) _{\equiv}$ mean here.

Is $\theta$ a 'sequence' of zero's and then a one at the i'th position? If so, how does one calculate something like $\alpha_{i}^{\delta{i}} \ \theta_{i} = \mathbb{mod} \ \mathit{\Pi}$
where $\alpha_{i} \in \{1, 0\}^{t}$ and $\{0, 1\}^{t}$ is a set of t-bit numbers. (Page 2; Section 1)

The definitions of the notation:

> Let $\mathit{\Pi} = \prod_{i=1}^{k}{p_{i}^{\delta_{i}}}$ be the $n$-bit product of the first $k$ primes with some small exponents $\delta_{i}$, and let $\Delta = \textrm{max}_{i}\delta_{i}$. We denote by $x = ( x_{1},\dots,x_{k} ) _{\equiv}$ the modular representation of $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\mathit{\Pi}}$, i.e., $x_{i} = x \bmod \ p_{i}^{\delta_{i}}$. For $i = 1, \dots, k$, one then defines  $\theta_{i} = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)_{\equiv}$ where the "$1$" stands for the $i^{\text{th}}$ position. It is obvious to see that we always have:
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\mathit{\Pi}}\qquad x = \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{i} \theta_{i} \bmod{\mathit{\Pi}}$$
> [some proof/reasoning here for the calculations below]
> $$\begin{align}\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\mathit{\Pi}} \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{\mathit{\Pi}} 
> &\Longleftrightarrow x_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p_{i}^{\delta_{i}}} \\
> &\Longleftrightarrow x_{i}^{\delta_{i}} \not\equiv 0 \pmod{ p_{i}^{\delta_{i}}} \\
> &\Longleftrightarrow x_{i}^{\delta_{i}} \theta_{i} \not\equiv 0 \pmod{\mathit{\Pi}} \;\text{for $i = 1, \dots, k$}
> \end{align}$$

Comment: I overhauled the formatting. Please double-check that I didn't make any serious mistakes. ... In the future: MathJax formatting is for the *mathematical expressions* in a passage, not the *full text* of it. (Of course, in some cases, a bit of text is best formatted within an expression, as with the "for" in the last line.) So, instead of a giant `$$...$$` expression littered with `\textrm`s enclosing the text, you should just have a regular paragraph peppered with `$...$`s and `$$...$$`s enclosing the math. (That said, I commend your considerable effort in transcribing the passage to MathJax!)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem? It's all you need to understand the notation.

Comment: @jjagmath I am, but I'm not sure how this relates to it

Comment: @blue Oh, yeah! I'm not sure why I didn't think of doing it this way. And thank you so much for all the work! Looks so much better now! :)

Comment: By CRT the quotient ring is a direct product of rings. Here  $\theta_i$ are the "basis vectors" that span the product, having $1$ in the $i$'th component and all others $0,\,$ so $\,(x_1,\ldots, x_k) = x_1 \theta_1 + \cdots + x_k \theta_k.\,$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) for an elementary introduction to CRT in vector language (more precisely *module* language but these may not be familiar yet).