# Which element in $\Bbb Z_{2024}$ corresponds to the triple of numbers $(1,3,22)$ in the product $\Bbb Z_8 \times \Bbb Z_{11} \times \Bbb Z_{23}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I know all 8 idempotents in $\Bbb Z_{2024}$ are:  $1265, 760, 1288, 737, 1496, 529, 0, 1$. I hope this helps somehow. Please help me, this question failed me in the exam (((

Comment: Did you cover the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @arthur Not if you consider the isomorphism as an isomorphism of rings. Given ring theory is tagged, and not group theory, it seems implied, if not specified in the question.

Comment: In group theory, $*$ is used to denote the free product. For the direct product, use `\times` to get $\times$. In Ring theory, $*$ is not a good symbol either.

Comment: You need only the idempotents $\,1265 \to (1,0,0),\ 1288\to (0,1,0),\,1496\to (0,0,1)\,$ to apply the common [CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, and the mention of idempotents should have tipped me off as well.