# Fermat’s little theorem and J. E. Phythian

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can man proof this Theorem step by step, specially when $$p_i\mid a?$$
This theorem is in book: Elementary number theory by Koshy on page 334

Let $$p_1, p_2, . . . , p_k$$ be any distinct primes, and let $a$ any positive integer, and
$$L = {\rm lcm}(p_1 − 1, p_2 − 1, . . . , p_{k} −1).$$ Then $$a^{L+1} \equiv a\pmod{p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k}.$$
i can not understand the proof in the book, Can anyone help me?

[image]
[excerpt added by Bill D.]

Comment: Where does Phythian enter?

Comment: Why cannot we say $a^{L+1}-a \equiv 0 \pmod{p_1\dots p_k}$ is true just because $p_i \mid a$?

Comment: @lhf, it's probably a reference in Koshy's book to a paper on the subject written by Phythian.

Comment: @lhf It seems to refer to a [1970 note in *Math. Gazette*"](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.2307/3613876) by J.E. Phythian,  Math. Dep., Univ. Dar es Salaam, Tanzania. It's a very strange reference for such an old well-known result.

Comment: Which step in the proof do you not understand?

Comment: @BillDubuque, great find, thanks!

Comment: i want to understand This: When $$p_i \mid a$$ then $$a^{L+1}≡a\hspace{3pt} mod\hspace{3pt}(p_1.p_2p_3. ...p_k)$$

Comment: Koshy's proof is incorrect if some $p_i\mid a,\,$ likely the source of your doubt. To fix it add the case that $\,p_i\mid a\,\Rightarrow\, \,p_i\mid a^{L+1}-a =:N,\,$ so this divisibilty always holds - both when $\,p_i\mid a,\,$ and when it does not, by the given proof via little Fermat; typo fix:  $\,(a^{\color{#c00}{p_i-1}})^{\ell/(p_i-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}.\ \ $

Comment: Since $N$ is divisible by the distinct primes $p_i$ it is also divisible by their product $P$ (provable either by FTA = existence & uniqueness of prime factorizations, or [lcm = product for coprimes,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1982395/242) or by iterating [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) or Euclid's Lemma, etc). Thus $\,P\mid a^{L+1}-a\,\Rightarrow\, a^{L+1}\equiv a\pmod{\! P}\ \ $

Comment: That case is also not handled in Phythian's paper, so it too is incorrect. It is a trivial case, for sure, but it needs to be mentioned in order to obtain a complete, correct proof.

Comment: But how we can from $$p_i\hspace{3pt} \mid( a^{L+1}-a)$$ go to and proof that $$p_1.p_2.p_3....p_k\hspace{3pt}\mid( a^{L+1}-a)$$

Comment: That is explained in my second last comment, which mentions a few methods to prove that any integer divisible by distinct primes is also divisible by their product. Note: you need to start your messages with "@Bill" for me to be notified that you have replied. Else I may never see them.